# Pointing a domain name

Tags: javascript, url

I've just pointed a domain name ([www.MyNewDomainName.com](http://www.MyNewDomainName.com)) to a website ([www.blabla.com/something](http://www.blabla.com/something)). The problem is that if I enter the website from [www.MyNewDomain.com](http://www.MyNewDomain.com) the event listeners written in JavaScript (pressing some keys on the keyboard) do not work until I press on the screen with mouse or press <kbd>tab</kbd> key. On the contrary entering site from [www.blabla.com/something](http://www.blabla.com/something) everything works immediately.
How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did a url cloak instead of a proper configurated domain pointer.

URL Cloaking is when your website domain name remains in the address bar of the browser "cloaking" the destination URL (web address) from all visitors’ eyes. The web surfers won't see the “forwarded to” web address in their browsers at all.

Sometimes the website is loaded in a frame, that's probebly why you have to click first. Can you give us the source of (www.MyNewDomainName.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any specifics, I would say try setting the focus of a field or simulate a click event onload, If you are using JQuery something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').click();
});
```